# Laravel vue SUM array data inside array

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have array of data which has array inside of it, in second array i need to sum one column and get the result back.

## Screenshot

[image: one]

## Code

`controller`

```
public function index()
{
  $zones = ZoneRegion::orderby('id', 'desc')->with(['areas', 'segments', 'links', 'cabels'])->get();
  return response()->json([
    'data' => $zones,
    'message' => 'Zona Wilayah berhasil diambil.'
  ]);
}
```

`component`

```
data() {
    return {
        regions: [],
    }
},
methods: {
    fetchRegions() {
        axios
        .get('/api/admin/zones', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.regions = response.data.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    },
}
```

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: I posted an answer, but now I believe that you only want to sum cable lengths for each row in your data array? Or do you want total length of all rows together?

Comment: Let me know what you need so I can update my answer, the reduce method shall be used either way.

Comment: @RobertKujawa thank you, yes i only need sum for each row. i'll try your code and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [js reduce method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) to sum all the cable lengths together.

```
data() {
    return {
        regions: []
    }
},
methods: {
    fetchRegions() {
        axios
        .get('/api/admin/zones', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.regions = response.data.data.map(region => ({
                ...region,
                totalCableLength: region.links.reduce((total, link) => {
                    return total + parseInt(link.cable_length);
                }, 0)
            }));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    }
}
```

This will save your regions just like you retrieved them from the server, but it will add the sum of all the links cable length to each region, it will be keyed by 'totalCableLength'.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code in component it does return the result but as i need to use it in my table it shows nothing (you know tables are looped, so i think this `getCableLength(data)` somehow should be pushed to `this.regions` maybe?)

Comment: i think your code sum all values at once, what i'm looking for is row based so let say (row 1 = 1000 & row 2 = 1500) but what i get now is total 2500

Comment: I updated my answer, so you can retrieve your total simply by looping through your regions array and accessing `region.totalCableLength`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, remove the semicolon. I update my answer again.

Comment: should be `}, 0) }));` less 1 `)` before `;`

Comment: variable isn't exist in my regions array https://ibb.co/wdf8mzv

Comment: It won't be in the response you get from Laravel, It will be on the Vue side. inside the regions array, in each region. Do you have vue devtools plugin installed?

Comment: Check the regions array in vue devtools each region will now have a property called totalCableLength with the sum of all links.

Comment: yes in here exist https://ibb.co/6RJhfQ0 but not printing in table

Comment: Show me your vue template code, how are you printing it? Are you using `v-for` ?

Comment: it was misspelling in my table, my apologize, is there any way  to add thousands comma into this numbers?

Comment: You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) to add commas each thousand